# TSQL Partition by with Order by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, partition

I noticed that when I use a partition by like below

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoryid
ORDER BY unitprice, productid) AS rownum,
categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
FROM Production.Products;
```

the result set returned to me accordingly in the proper partiton and order.

Does that mean I do not have to provide an Order BY clause at the end to absolutely guarantee the order that I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

To guarantee the result order, you *must* use an `ORDER BY` that applies to the outermost query. Anything else is just coincidence.

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoryid
ORDER BY unitprice, productid) AS rownum,
categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
FROM Production.Products
ORDER BY categoryid,unitprice,productid;
```

`ORDER BY` has two roles:

- To actually define how another feature works. This is true when using `TOP`, say, or within an `OVER()` partition function. It doesn't *require* sorting to occur, it just says "this definition only makes sense if we consider the rows in the result set to occur in a particular order - here's the one I want to use"
- To dictate the sort order of the result set. This is true when it's an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost statement that is part of a particular query - not in a subquery, a CTE, an `OVER()` paritition function, etc.

Occasionally you will experience it being used in both senses at once - when the outermost statement includes a `TOP` or `OFFSET`/`FETCH`, then it's used for both purposes.

Comment: +1 the `ORDERBY` inside the `OVER()` clause only dictates how the row number values are assigned, it guarantees nothing about the order ofg the final result set

Comment: I am struggling to comprehend this below,


INSERT INTO Sales.MyOrders(orderid, custid, empid, orderdate)
SELECT
NEXT VALUE FOR Sales.SeqOrderIDs OVER(ORDER BY orderid),
custid, empid, orderdate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 1;

The book says the "OVER clause with an ORDER BY list to control the order in which
the sequence values are assigned to the result rows"

If I can get clarification that would be great